# LaravelValidator package

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-validation, lumen-5.2

I use laravel validator with l5 repository and lumen 5.2 and ran in to 2 problems:

1. I cant use unique as a rule. I get "presence verifier has not been set"
2. I cant set custom rules. In the AppServiceProvider I set:

   ```
   $this->app['validator']->extend('my_rule', function ($attribute,       $value, $parameters)
   {
        //My rule
   }
   ```

   this works i I do:

   ```
   $test = \Validator::make(['test'=>$value], [
       'test' => 'my_rule',
   ]);
   ```

   but not with my l5 repository rule

Does anyone know if I can use the unique rule and define my own rules using LaravelValidator? It seems to be using the Validator Factory.